# I have been locked out of a Google account because I changed phone numbers

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, account-recovery

I have an old Google account I would like to get into. I know to a certainty the following:

1. username
2. password
3. phone number I registered the account with

I changed phone numbers so I can't receive Google's call or email.  When I click on "I don't have my phone" it takes me to "Google needs more info to verify it's you". and tells me to sign in using a wifi network and device I've used before. I try going to account recovery and it just does the same thing, it never asks me any questions or anything.

Is there anything else I can try? I don't seem to have any verification backup codes, nor does it even give me the chance to enter any.